# GET-POINTER-VALUE - Unix behaivor?

Tags: progress-4gl

*How can I obtain a mem pointer with progress using GET-POINTER-VALUE....?
In Windows works fine:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE vUNO  AS MEMPTR.
DEFINE VARIABLE vDOS  AS MEMPTR.
DEFINE VARIABLE vTRES AS MEMPTR.
DEFINE VARIABLE sUNO  AS CHARACTER.
DEFINE VARIABLE sDOS  AS CHARACTER.
DEFINE VARIABLE sTRES AS CHARACTER.
DEFINE VARIABLE rUno  AS MEMPTR.
/*Para prueba, poner algo a UNO, DOS y TRES.*/
DEFINE VARIABLE PTR AS MEMPTR.
ASSIGN sUNO                 = "Uno" 
       sDOS                 = "Dos" 
       sTRES                = "Tres"

       SET-SIZE(vUNO  )     = LENGTH(sUNO ) * 2
       SET-SIZE(vDOS  )     = LENGTH(sDOS ) * 2 
       SET-SIZE(vTRES )     = LENGTH(sTRES) * 2

       PUT-STRING(vUNO , 1) = sUNO                  
       PUT-STRING(vDOS , 1) = sDOS 
       PUT-STRING(vTRES, 1) = sTRES.
SET-SIZE(PTR) =  4  /*Apuntador a vUNO  -> 1*/
               + 4  /*Apuntador a vDOS  -> 5*/
               + 4. /*Apuntador a vTRES -> 9*/
/* 
  NOTA: 
       4 porque en arquitcturas a 32 bits apuntadores miden 4 bytes. 
       Checar en Unix porque Hp-Ux (de Axa) es a 64 bits (apuntadores a 8 bytes).
*/
/* [1] 2 3 4 [5] 6 7 8 [9] 10 11 12 */
MESSAGE PROGRAM-NAME(1) SKIP                          
    GET-STRING(vUNO,1 ) "/" GET-POINTER-VALUE(vUNO)  SKIP    
    GET-STRING(vDOS,1 ) "/" GET-POINTER-VALUE(vDOS)  SKIP
    GET-STRING(vTRES,1) "/" GET-POINTER-VALUE(vTRES) SKIP
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
```

/**************************************************************************/
It returns:

```
---------------------------
Información
---------------------------
C:\GMM2000\Temp\p19350.cmp 
Uno / 87066920 
Dos / 85914720 
Tres / 85914744 
---------------------------
Aceptar   
---------------------------
```

but with the same code Unix returns:

```
---------------------------
Información
---------------------------
/gmm2000/p13659.cmp 
Uno / ? 
Dos / ? 
Tres / ? 
---------------------------
Aceptar   
---------------------------
```

Please HEEEEEELLLLPPPPP!!!!*

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code on 10.2B Linux.  It seems to work:

```
  ┌────────── Information ──────────┐
  │ /home/tom/p04012_Untitled1.ped  │
  │         Uno / 16817200          │
  │         Dos / 16992512          │
  │        Tres / 16992544          │
  │ ─────────────────────────────── │
  │              <OK>               │
  └─────────────────────────────────┘
```

Know that we know that you are running 64 bit Progress v9 on HPUX...

In a 64 bit environment GET-POINTER-VALUE() returns a 64 bit result.  But Progress v9 does not have an int64 data type.  Try assigning the result to a DECIMAL variable.  That should be able to hold the value.

Comment: what kind of permissions have your user account with you tested?

Comment: I'm using HP-UX / 64bits , someone knows if it could be the cause for error?

Comment: it could be. see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

The HP-UX 64bit AVM doesn't do 64bit pointers for some of the releases, as the external interfaces only do 32bits.I forget which version implemented full 64 bit pointers though - that would be a question to ask PSC TS.